# Should I send Link rel=preload headers when there is a redirect before the final HTML page?

Tags: http-headers, preload

I'm trying to optimise the speed of some web page by adding the `Link` HTTP header to instruct the browser to preload some assets and data that is used on the web page. However, most visitors will get redirected first, before they get to the actual HTML page.

Does it make sense to already include the `Link` header in the response that contains the redirect? Or will the browser not use those assets for the redirected page anyway, so can I better leave them out to prevent unnecessary requests?

### Example

The user first opens `/initial`, and gets redirected from there:

```
GET /initial HTTP/1.1

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Link: </static/css/bundle.css>; rel=preload; as=style
Location: /final
```

The browser then follows the redirect to `/final`:

```
GET /final HTTP/1.1

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Link: </static/css/bundle.css>; rel=preload; as=style

<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/bundle.css">
...
```

So, does it make sense that the `Link` header is already included in the first `302` response, or can I better leave it out there?